# How does browser handle redirect_uri in OAuth2?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I understand that `redirect_uri` is a crucial part of the OAuth flow but my question is how does the browser actually handle the redirect request coming back from IDP after success authenticated?
I am very confused becuase:

1. Response is 200 instead of 302 redirect
2. No location head in response neither

**So how does browser analyse this response and behave the action to redirect you to the address in `redirect_uri`?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic when it comes to browsers handling redirect - either through a 30X response code or some Javascript actions.

Take Azure AD for example, assume you have logged in a Microsoft account. If you can capture the response content of your OAuth2 request (endpoint is like [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id...](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7Btenant_id%7D/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id...)), there will be a hidden form -

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Working...</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="https://localhost/redirect_url">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_token" value="ey..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="state" value="state..." />
    <input type="hidden" name="session_state" value="guid..." />
    <noscript>
      <p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </noscript>
  </form>
  <script language="javascript">document.forms[0].submit();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the form includes your id_token. The script automatically triggers a submission action, and the action navigates to your endpoint, thus the redirect

Comment: Thank you so much sir! Much appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

Applications that use languages and frameworks like PHP, Java, Python, Ruby, and .NET must specify authorized redirect URIs. **The redirect URIs are the endpoints to which the OAuth 2.0 server can send responses.**

Hence, the response 200 which you are seeing - it means that the Auth 2.0 server has successfully sent the response to the specified Reply URL.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But my question is not what `redirect_uri` is but **how** does browser handle this response and perform the actually redirect action.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, the app will send a response to the Redirect URI.